# Zend Studio selecting full Block

Tags: selection, block, zend-studio

Is there any way to select a full block in Zend Studio? 
We can just use

> Ctrl + Shift + P

and jump to end of the block but is there any way to select the block code like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SHIFT + DOWN combination

And you could change the TOGGLE MARK OCCURENCE MODE (ALT+SHIFT+O)
then if you double click on { it's selecting block.